# Laravel session clear on POST AJAX hit?

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, authentication

I have created some cart data in the session having key cart data when I hit any post ajax route the data of the session reset automatically. where am wrong in this here the controller where i check for user phone no for checking login status but when i hit this with ajax the session data clear automatically .

MY controller:

```
public function check(Request $request) {
       //dd(Session::all());

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'phone' => 'required|numeric|',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // return redirect()->back()->with('errors',$validator->errors())->withInput($request->only('phone', 'remember'));
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $validator->errors()], 403);
        } else {

            $string = strlen('+91' . $request->phone);

            if ($string < 13) {

                return response()->json(['success' => 'invalid', 'message' => 'Please Enter a Valid Phone Number'], 401);
            }

            //dd($request->phone);

            $data = DB::table('users')->where('phone', $request->phone)->get();

            if ($data->count() <= 0) {


                return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 1, 'phone' => $request->phone));
            } else {
                return response()->json(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'The phone has already been taken.Please Login', 'phone' => $request->phone), 403);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my ajax call is :

```
axios.post(process.env.MIX_BASEURL+'/checkphone',

                        vm.checkphone,

                        )
                        .then(response => {

                            console.log(response)                                                 
                        if(response.status==200){
                            //alert('no can register');
                            if(response.data.message==1){
                                let phone_no=response.data.phone;
                                //sendotp(phone_no);
                                $("#phone1").addClass("is-valid");
                                showRegisterFormnext(phone_no);
                            }
                        }

                        })
                        .catch(error => {

                           var errors = error.response
                            console.log(error.response)
                            ///IF EMPTY FIELDS FOUND///
                            if (errors.status == 403) {
                                //alert('somthing went wrong')
                                if (errors.data.message) {
                                   vm.errorsPhone = true
                                   $("#phone1").addClass("is-invalid");
                                    vm.PhoneError = errors.data.message
                                 toastr["error"](errors.data.message);

                    //                  swal({
                    //     title: "Oops!",
                    //     text: "no alredy exist please login",
                    //     icon: "error",
                    //     button: "ok"
                    // });
                                      showLoginForm();   
                                }else{
                                   if (errors.data.error.phone) {
                                        vm.errorsPhone = true
                                         $("#phone1").addClass("is-invalid");
                                        vm.PhoneError = _.isArray(errors.data.error.phone) ? errors.data.error.phone[0] : errors.data.error.phone
                                        toastr["error"](vm.PhoneError);
                                        //alert(vm.PhoneError)
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            if (errors.status == 401) {

                                  toastr["error"](errors.data.message);
                                }

                        });
            }
```